# Transição Fragments ao voltar

Tags: android, fragment, drawer-layout

Tenho um DrawerLayout que controla meus fragments. Porém estou com o seguinte problema: se eu estou no fragment A o item menu correspondente fica em destaque, ao selecionar o fragment b , o item também é destacado corretamente. Porém ao clicar no botão de voltar, embora volte do B para o A normalmente, o item de menu selecionado não muda. Existe alguma função ou método que controle isso?

Comment: NavigationView.setCheckedItem(@IntRes id);

Comment: Infelizmente não funcionou